# How to send data from child to parent using ElementRef and resolveComponentFactory in Angular?

Tags: angular, templates, binding, factory, elementref

The childbox which I create from inside the parent on the fly contains a close button which triggers a close function which is actually an EventEmitter whom message should reach the parent somehow in order to destroy the child component with "this.child.destroy();"

The code in the parent in order to create the child:

```
childComponentRef: any;
@ViewChild('childComponentcontainer', {static : false, read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;

createchildComponent(message:any) {
this.entry.clear();
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);
this.childComponentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
this.childComponentRef.instance.data = message;
}

closechildComponent($event){
console.log("dest")
//this.childComponentRef.destroy();
```

}

and the html

```
<template #childComponentcontainer (close) = "closechildComponent($event)"></template>
```

or

```
<template #childComponentcontainer></template>
```

and the child

```
onClose() {
this.close.emit("close");
```

}

The child shows but when clicking the close button nothing happens. How could I fix this?

Normally I would have used

```
<child
(close) = "closebox($event)"
[data] = "data">
</child>
```

but here I'can't add the (close) binding because I create the component on the fly

https://angular-excmcj.stackblitz.io

Thank you!

Comment: hello @a can you create a minimum working example @ [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? you're trying to close the child element from the parent?

Comment: Exactly, I try to get an event from the child in order to close the child from the parent. The problem is I'm not sure how to bind the event...

Comment: I would say that you need to create an input on the child, and pass the event from the parent (does this make sense to you?)

Comment: I did this to send data from parent to child, but the issue is I need to send data from child to parent with @output. I also did this but I have to binfd this event in the childcomponent on the fly: <child #childComponentcontainer (close) = "closechildComponent($event)"></child>

Comment: it's easier to help with an example

Comment: @rmoja Firstly thank you a lot for the support! here the example https://angular-excmcj.stackblitz.io